# How to find condition that start char in UTF-8 file is read, using FileStream and StreamReader?

Tags: c#-4.0, utf-8, io, stream

In C# .NET 4.0 (really 4.5.2), my code reads a UTF-8 file.

```
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            BufferedStream stream = new BufferedStream(fstream);

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, new UTF8Encoding())) {              
                int i;
                while((i = reader.Read()) > -1) {
                    //a guess at a condition that is true I.F.F. reader has read character 1 of the file
                    if (stream.Position == (0 + sizeof(char)) || stream.Position == (0 + sizeof(int)) ) {
                        //while loop has reader read through all characters, 
                        //but within this block, the reader has surely read character 1?
                        char c = (char)i;


                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                return 0;
            }
```

I.F.F. we reach the condition that StreamReader reads the start character of the UTF-8 file, then run some function on the first character read.

With a FileStream and StreamReader used in reading a UTF-8 file, how do you know whether the aforementioned condition is met?

I am looking for an answer, please, that uses a property or method that already exists in the C# .NET 4.0 System.IO namespace. I thought use of the Stream.Position (BufferedStream.Position) property is the obvious way to find out where (i.e. at what character) in the file the reader is, but in trying a UTF-8 file that starts with some character in `'0'` to `'9'` (48 to 57), the loop with reader.Read() reads that char, and `stream.Position = 43` . I don't know why 43 of all integral values is the value of `stream.Position` after the 1st character is read, or what the 43 means.

**update**: As the loop iterates and the reader reads more characters, the `stream.Position` value remains at 43. I don't know the Position property is useful then.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The existing code is not very revealing. I can't make out what the point of this is.

Comment: Read UTF file into C# `char` or `String` values. The overall problem is to do some action as a function of the `char`'s locations in the file and the `char` values. There is an expected format so a `n`th line of the file has its `char` values read and used differently than line `n + 1` or `n + 2`. The `i`th character of line `n` might change one field, and the `char` `i + 1` sets another field and changes state somewhere. Does that help?

Comment: OK, can you just use File.ReadAllText/Lines and process the strings you get from that?

Comment: Sure, or use StreamReader.ReadToEnd() of many other ways to do this; read `char` into a huge blob of memory, but that would be criticized versus  reading the data in a buffered way, like with a BufferedStream.

Comment: BufferedStream is unnecessary because FileStream has buffering built-in. (You seem to be a Java person). Can you use File.EnumerateLines?

Comment: I see you've read or know more of the System.IO namespace documentation than I have. I see no reason *not* to use StreamReader here.

Comment: Right, you can use StreamReader here successfully. It just seems easier the other way. The solution is probably obvious once you iterate over a sequence of lines. All position calculations can then be done on normal strings. I just wanted to let you know about that. Maybe xanatos' answer will solve the problem, too.

Comment: I was looking at the [StreamReader source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs) and hm it has buffering too. If you see a much better way to do this, then maybe post an answer and you might even get votes, although I'm probably going to go with StreamReader as I've been working on it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool first = true;    

while((i = reader.Read()) > -1) 
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        // Do first character things
    }
```

Note that the concept of first character is complex: what happens if the first glyph is `è`, that occupies two bytes in the file? The stream position will be at least 2 :-)

In general, you can check what the `Position` of the `StreamReader.BaseStream` is, but that `Position` is nearly useless, because there could be multiple levels of caching, or simply because for reading a single `char`, the `StreamReader` could have consumed 1-4 bytes (`à` is one byte, while some Unicode characters are long 4 bytes)... And then UTF8 files can have a BOM (an initial header long 3 bytes). That too is normally skipped from `StreamReader`.

Still, if you want, you can subclass the entire `StreamReader` class, overriding all the `Read*`, and keeping an internal flag `SomethingHasBeenRead`. It isn't difficult (everything is `virtual` in `StreamReader`)... It is only a little long to do.

Comment: @T.Webster You have it all wrong. a .NET `char` is two bytes, the UTF8 code for a unicode char can be 1-4 bytes. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aè").Length == 3`.

Comment: @T.Webster And even that is a little imprecise... In Unicode there are like 1 million possible code points. All can be represented in UTF32, that uses 4 bytes per code point. Using UTF16 (like the C# `char`) you use 2 or 4 bytes, so 1 or 2 `char`, depending on the code point. If you use 2 `char`, they are called "surrogate pairs". Using UTF16 each code point can be represented in 1-4 bytes. When you use `Encoding.UTF8`, a string is "virtually" converted in its code points (so grouping surrogate pairs) and then converted to UTF8.

Comment: yes I considered this kind of approach but the reason I was looking for a solution that used some class/member in the .NET 4.0 System.IO namespace already, is that it seems cleaner and less error-prone than  to write your own variables down like this.What if a bug makes these variables invalid? Moreover, a generic way to find what character we are at in the file [btw char size is 2 bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w(v=vs.140).aspx) btw), using something like BufferedStream.Position was what I was hoping for.

Comment: @T.Webster The simple thing is: there is no way that I know to check if the `StreamReader` has read at least a character or not. (added some lines to the response)

Comment: It's not exactly the answer I was hoping for, but you have my +1. To subclass is probably the best way to go about this. The `Read()` method is an `override`, and I can basically count the `char` characters read, which gives me close to what I wanted, to know with certainty that I am at/Read the character 1, 2, *n*th (matched by some Regex) in the UTF file.

Comment: @T.Webster Note that `StreamReader.ReadLine()` and `StreamReader.ReatToEnd()` don't use `StreamReader.Read()`! (nor the other methods). They are all independent.

Comment: I see. btw, I will end up using using Regular Expressions probably, and take actions on `char` values matching the expressions. Not sure whether to override Readline() or Read(). But the UTF8 file will, in this case, be formatted into lines, so it makes some sense to override ReadLine(), although a matched `char` `i` of a line will change state differently than `char` `i + 1` or `i + 2`, so maybe `Read()` makes as much sense to override.

Comment: @T.Webster Be aware that `ReadLine()` doesn't return the end-of-line, so you are off-by-1 or off-by-2 for each line after the first.

Comment: That's fine, the `\r` `\r\n` values don't have any use unless I implement Read() and use them to count the lines. [StreamReader source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,9e4b81292b314eba) shows the find-end-of-line code in Readline() may not be so trivial, making it worth overriding. And it implements reading the `char`s through buffering and *not concatenation*, so probably no advantage to override Read() here.